# Accented characters are looking distorted only in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, font-face

I've added the fonts with @font-face and the fonts are looking as expected in all the browsers but in firefox.

Here is the website I'm working on https://fashionunited.fr/

The issue appears only in accented characters and with bold and in some cases with normal font-weight.

The fonts are also loading with fontfaceobserver.js

Here is my code:

JS file and css file

```
(function( w ){
    // if the class is already set, we're good.
    if( w.document.documentElement.className.indexOf( "fonts-loaded" ) > -1 ){
        return;
    }
    var fontA = new w.FontFaceObserver( "Open Sans", [{
        weight: 300
    },{
        weight: 400
    }, {
        weight: 700
    }]);
     var fontB = new w.FontFaceObserver( "Droid Serif", [{
        weight: 400
    }, {
        weight: 700
    }]);
    w.Promise
        .all([fontA.check(), fontB.check()])
        .then(function(){
            w.document.documentElement.className += " fonts-loaded";
        });
}( this ));


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-bold-700webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-bold-700webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-bold-700webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Droid Serif';
    src: url('../fonts/droidserif-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/droidserif-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/droidserif-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Droid Serif';
    src: url('../fonts/droidserif-bold-700webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/droidserif-bold-700webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/droidserif-bold-700webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing that some of your accented e's are being generated with two characters and some with one. Some are done as if they were `e&#769;` (e followed by an accent that's supposed to go on top of it, but clearly isn't), others were done as if `&#233;`. It looks like it's the former that has the odd appearance.

Comment: hi @MaxStarkenburg thanks for your reply. the problem starts when I put the fonts in production because in local all works fine.